# Django syncdb doesn't create db tables

Tags: django-syncdb

I've been troubleshooting this error with no luck.

TemplateSyntaxError at /signup/

Caught DatabaseError while rendering: relation "signup_product" does not exist
LINE 1: ..."duration", "signup_product"."duration_type" FROM "signup_pr...

What I've discovered is when I run manage.py syncdb, it is not creating any tables in my database. This is an empty database, which explains the above error.

I ran manage.py sqlall myapp and it displayed all the models in myapp.models

I can start the shell and import myapp just fine.

So why doesn't manage.py syncdb create my tables?

Answer (score 0):

This is before I learned about South.  I wasn't using migrate, so syncdb wasn't adding my new models.